# Convert .OBJ to JSON format with libgdx

Tags: json, libgdx, .obj, wavefront

I'm working on a project where we need to convert .OBJ models into .G3DJ (JSON) format on the fly. I've tried with this code I've founded in google code.

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ImportingModelsFromBlender

```
  ObjLoader loader = new ObjLoader();
  StillModel model = loader.loadObj(Gdx.files.internal("data/model.obj"), true);
  G3dExporter.export(models, Gdx.files.absolute("data/model.g3d"));
```

But `StillModel` and `G3DExporter` cannot be found in libgdx.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the new wiki not at the old. That entry is from 2011.

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Grapics3DQuickStart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The libgdx-users wiki is not up to date. Converting an OBJ file to G3DJ (or G3DB) can be done using [fbx-conv](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv), which is a command line utility (you can call it from code if you like).

Also make sure to update to the nightly build. StillModel is no longer supported (and does not support the G3DJ (JSON) file format).

It is recommended not to use OBJ (although it is still supported). Instead use FBX (converted to G3Dx), which supports more functionality than OBJ.

Comment: excelent thank you. Do you think there is a way to do this work in an Android device?

Comment: No, fbx-conv relies on the FBX SDK, which afaik is not available for android.